# Anyway to keep HAML dry in Rails using Foundation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, haml, dry

I'm trying to make a responsive design using hide and show classes.
The only variables for this would be the class names.
I can't figure out how to assign the appropriate classes without
having to duplicate the content. Basically i just want to change the
columns and rows to wrap if the screen width is medium or down.
I would want to show the same content in two different rows for smaller
screen size.  There must be an easy way to do this?

```
%section.dark-footer
  .row
    .small-12.columns
      .row
        .small-7.columns.minibar.hide-for-medium-down
          %ul.inline-list
            %li.footbar= link_to "Home", root_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "Product", about_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "Customize", customize_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "About", about_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "Partners", partners_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "Sign-up", register_path
            %li.footbar= link_to "Sign-In", new_user_session_path
        .small-4.columns
          = link_to (image_tag "icons/facebook.png", class: "icon", id: "facebook"),     "http://facebook.com/test", target: "_blank"
          = link_to (image_tag "icons/twitter.png", class: "icon", id: "twitter"), "http://twitter.com/test", target: "_blank"
          = link_to (image_tag "icons/linkedin.png", class: "icon", id: "linkedin"), "http://linkedin.com/test", target: "_blank"
          = link_to (image_tag "icons/google.png", class: "icon", id: "google"), "http://google.com/test", target: "_blank"
          = link_to (image_tag "icons/pinterest.png", class: "icon", id: "pinterest"), "http://pinterest.com/test", target: "_blank"
%section.orange-footer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller knows the device. If you are willing to bet that the user-agent string is enough of information to use when deciding what class to set, do something like this:

```
.foo.bar{class: @responsive_classes[:whatever]}
```

Basically, you create a hash of classes for the items that change to implement responsive design in your controller then consume them in your view.

That said, there are a lot of client-side solutions to this that rely on much more specific knowledge of the browser in which your app is running. Think about [breakpoints](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/) or something like that in conjunction with a bit of javascript or coffeescript to do the work.